# Cannot convert to the type 'System.String' required by parameter. Specified method is not supported

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import a CSV and then create multiple users from it. So far I have written this, when I had 1 user it worked without using the for loop but now that I am iterating through it, I am getting error 'cannot convert to the type'.
Can someone explain why is it happening even though its an array and I am iterating through it one at a time? I tried couple of variations but some failed with this error and others with 'A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values'.

```
$OU = "OU=test,DC=domain,DC=local"
$Users = Import-Csv C:\Users\testuser\Users.csv
$FirstName = $Users.First
$LastName = $Users.Last
$EmpId = $Users.EmpId
$Domain = domain.local
$Password = "Friday123!"

foreach ($Obj in $Users.EmpId) {
    New-ADUser -Name $Obj -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName -UserPrincipalName $obj@$domain -Path $OU -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
}
```

Here is how my .csv file which has first 13 users in it:

```
First,Last,EmpId
Test,User1,TSTUSR01
Test,User2,TSTUSR02
Test,User3,TSTUSR03
Test,User4,TSTUSR04
Test,User5,TSTUSR05
Test,User6,TSTUSR06
Test,User7,TSTUSR07
Test,User8,TSTUSR08
Test,User9,TSTUSR09
Test,User10,TSTUSR10
Test,User11,TSTUSR11
Test,User12,TSTUSR12
Test,User13,TSTUSR13
```

Comment: What is $UserData?  `set-strictmode -v 1`

Comment: Please show us the _full error message_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your variables outside of the foreach section, also you need to use `$Users` instead of `$UserData.EmpId`

I Think this should make more sense, also, note that `$obj@$domain` is wrong, I update it to `"$FirstName@$domain"`, update it if needed...

```
$OU = "OU=test,DC=domain,DC=local"
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Users\testuser\Users.csv
$Domain = domain.local

foreach ($Obj in $Users) {
$FirstName = $Obj.First
$LastName = $Obj.Last
$EmpId = $Obj.EmpId
$Password = "Friday123!"
New-ADUser -Name $EmpId -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName -UserPrincipalName "$FirstName@$domain" -Path $OU -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
}
```